# How to release Photoshop CS6 export in sandboxie software?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-cs6, sandboxie

When I run CS6 in sandboxie and I want to export a file from CS6 then I get following question from sandboxie:

[image]

And if I want to use photoshop batch editing then this question is annoying and and prevents saving the output file.
Does anyone know how to disable this question? Does anyone have a similar experience?

Comment: Run PS outside sandbox

Comment: @RomeoNinov i must use sandboxie because i want to run batch editing in multiple photoshop cs6 and edit 10000 number of images!

Comment: Have you consider using different software for this action. For example ImageMagick can do a lot and will much easy to run several instances in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

If you want Sandboxie to write directly to a specific folder on your host, then you'll need to enable direct access.  In order to export from photoshop Sandboxie version you must add export folder to above list.

[image]